# How to best implement something like shortcodes in Grails

Tags: grails

How can I best implement something like shortcodes (thats what it's called in Wordpress) in Grails.

I have a Grails application where the user can input text. This text is saved in the Database. The Text should contain something like "shortcodes":

```
class Page(){

String text = "please display [form A] above here."

}
```

In my view I display the value text from my domain Object.

```
${domainObject.text}
```

eg: "[form A]" should display a referenced Form A in the position where it was put in the text.

What's the best way I can do this in Grails.

Comment: Looks like you need to provide a better example of what you want. I am able to understand is that user input Click on formA. Then formA should become a link.

Comment: tried to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best approach is to use `SimpleTemplateEngine`. Using this you could have standard `${}` block to specify variables.

Use method like below:

```
String renderTemplate(Reader template, Map bindings) {
        try {
            def engine = new groovy.text.SimpleTemplateEngine()
            return engine.createTemplate(template).make(bindings)
        } catch (MissingPropertyException mpe) {
            log.error("Missing property in template binding", mpe)
        }
        return ""
    }
```

Example:

```
String text = "please display ${formA} above here."

String parsedText = renderTemplate(new StringReader(text),[formA:'http://www.yourlink.com'])
```

Hope it helps!!